# How can I remove the spaces when combining rows with Array Formula Query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the EXPORT tab, I'd like to combine all data from column A. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IAZohjYZW-m7G06UyQ4IpEBVqNBY0lYJsH5o5hEHrnI/edit?usp=sharing

Since it's more than 50000 characters, I used this formula based on what I got from the this forum:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(A1:A149500,,100000))
```

It works, however, it creates a space for each row. I need to remove the space. Please help!

Comment: without any scripts you can copy the result into new cell and run CTRL+H where you remove the spaces

Comment: I mean it automatically creates a space at the end of each row. For example:

Row 1: Hello
Row 2: There

When I use the formula, it creates: Hello There

It should be: HelloThere

Note: I have more than 50000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Use the [substitue function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) to delete the generated blank spaces:

`=Substitute(ArrayFormula(query(A1:A149500,,100000))," ","")`

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)